# Use jquery variable to add class to element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get a specific class name that starts with 'size-' from an img tag, store that entire class name as a variable, and then pass the variable using addClass() to the img parent .wp-caption div.

HTML

```
<div id="attachment_101" style="width: 470px" class="wp-caption alignleft">
    <img class="wp-image-101 size-medium" src="http://192.168.0.8/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/01picAC-460x345.jpg" alt="01picAC" width="460" height="345">
    <p class="wp-caption-text">Even though 3-D graphics have been used in the Repair Manual and New Car Features, the 3-D graphics had not been used for technical training.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.post img').each(function() {
    var imgSize = this.className.match(/\bsize-[^\s]+\b/);
    $(this).parent('.wp-caption').addClass(imgSize);
});
```

My problem is that the variable imgSize is not being added as a class.

I can get it to work with:

```
$('.post img').each(function() {
    var imgSize = this.className.match(/\bsize-[^\s]+\b/);
    $(this).parent('.wp-caption').attr('class', imgSize);
});
```

...but that removes the existing align.. class which is needed.

I need to figure out how to get the variable which is 'size-[whatever]' added to the classes for the .wp-caption div.

Please help - I have been banging my head against a wall for an hour now trying to figure this out.

Comment: *hint :* `regex.match()` returns an array

Comment: hint2: `console.log(imgSize);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.post img').each(function() {
    var imgSize = this.className.match(/\bsize-[^\s]+\b/)[0];
    $(this).parent('.wp-caption').addClass(imgSize);
});
```

Comment: Works! Can you tell me what adding the zero does? Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: your var `imgSize` is an array as @adeneo points out. the `[0]` on the end is simply to get the first string in your array.